# Can I toggle word-wrapping on/off quickly in Gedit?

Tags: gedit

Depending on nature of the text, sometimes line wrapping is convenient, sometimes it is just confusing. And every time I need to switch this (pretty frequently) I have to do to View - Preferences - Enable text wrapping - Close - four clicks, not mentioning all the hand, eye and thought motion. Can this be done a quicker way?

Most text editors have this two clicks away (in a menu) at maximum, some have it on a toolbar or a hot key, but I couldn't find any quick way in Gedit. Maybe there is a hot key I don't know?

Comment: You could leave the preferences window open while you edit
or alt+e>e>alt+w works too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at this Text-Wrap-Plugin: http://hartmann-it-design.de/gedit/TextWrap/

I have not tested it myself, but it may serve yout needs.

Comment: Does it work in Gedit 3.10 versions? I tried to install it under ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins and gedit doesn't pick it up.

Answer (score 50):

In gedit 3.18 text wrapping can be turned on and off from the status bar.

[image]

Comment: Great! This works per-file unlike the way using Preferences.

Comment: This should be the approved answer.

Answer (score 13):

Edit -> Preferences

under the view tab check enable text wrapping

[image]

Comment: This is the method that was presented in the question - the OP was looking for an alternative to this method.

Comment: Using built-in keyboard shortcuts for this would be: `alt+e, e, alt+w` ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such shortcut that I know of, and the [gedit documentation](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/KeyboardShortcuts) confirms it.

There is a way in Gnome to add your own shortcuts, but it is meant for menu options. I don't think it will work with a function which is activated by checking a checkbox in the preferences. If you still want to try it, follow this:

```
Activate this feature

    * Run gconf-editor and go to /desktop/gnome/interface/
    * Check the 'can_change_accels' option
    * no need to restart anything, just close gconf-editor

Change menu shortcuts in your apps

    * Start your application : Shotwell here
    * Place your mouse on the menu you want to change
    * Press the key combination : you'll see your shortcut appear in the menu
```

(Instruction written by [Bubblegum](http://Bubblegum))

Answer (score 1):

### For gEdit v3

Use the Text Wrap plugin on [live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins/](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins/) :

> **Text Wrap**
>      A remake of the Text Wrap plugin from gedit 2. I changed the name
>   to toggletextwrap because it seems textwrap is already in the name
>   space somehow. Files: [toggletextwrap.plugin](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=toggletextwrap.plugin) and [toggletextwrap.py](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=toggletextwrap.py)

Install it using [@fossfreedom's](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) instructions on [How do I install a plugin for gEdit v3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61785/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-for-gedit-v3), specifically [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/61786/47291).

Comment: Eesh. Somehow I downvoted this. I definitely didn't mean to. And I did it too long ago to fix? Meanwhile, all links are broken.