# How do I install a plugin for gEdit v3?

Tags: gedit, plugins

I just installed the ubuntu 11.10, and I want to install a [plugin for gEdit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gedit-fileset/).

I unpacked the plugin to the following folder: `~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins` but in the gedit doesn't show up the plugin.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### gEdit 3

The version of gEdit in Oneiric & above is v3 built using gtk+3 libraries.  The plugin folder locations are slightly different than from gEdit v2.

Every plugin needs at least two files.

One file (pluginname.plugin) is to tell `gedit`:

- where the plugin can be found,
- what it's called,
- a short description,
- who is the author, etc.

This file is in the `.desktop` format.

The second file is the actual code.

Both of these files need to be placed in either:

- the system-wide plugins directory `/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/`, or
- in the user plugins directory, which may have to be manually created - `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/`.

### Installing Plugins

First create the plugin folder:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins
```

Now create a `.plugin` file using gedit N.B. these files have the format:

```
[Plugin]
Loader=python
Module=examplepy
IAge=3
Name=Example py
Description=A Python plugin example
Authors=Jesse van den Kieboom <jesse@icecrew.nl>
Copyright=Copyright © 2006 Jesse van den Kieboom <jesse@icecrew.nl>
Website=http://www.gedit.org
```

<sub>[source](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo)</sub>

---

For your v2 plugin you already have a file called `project-manager.gedit-plugin` so you can rename it:

```
mv project-manager.gedit-plugin project-manager.plugin
```

Then edit the plugin file and change the section header to "[Plugin]"

You will now see this in your gedit plugin list.

However for me it threw errors about "import gedit, gtk, gtk.glade".

You need to change the source code to import the gtk+3 variants - called python introspection.

An excellent tutorial for converting from gtk+2 to gtk+3 see

- http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Note that there is a good library of third party plugins for gedit 3 here: https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins#third_party. For those that missed it in the section above the critical bit for a plugin being found by gedit 3 is that the plugin has a `.plugin` extension. If it has a `.gedit-plugin` extension then it is an old version.

Answer (score 11):

2016 Update

To install all the gedit plugins, try:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
```

This worked great on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm currently using gedit version 3.10.4.

You will need to activate them by navigating to Edit - Preferences - Plugins. Then select the desired plugins to activate.

Comment: To be more precise (as installing a third-party plugin made me crazy), this are the steps to go (from terminal): 1) sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gedit-bc-dev-plugins/releases; 2) sudo apt-get update; 3) sudo apt-get install <plugin-name> (e.g. sudo apt-get install gedit-classbrowser3g-plugin). Cheers!

Comment: umbe1987  ppa:gedit-bc-dev-plugins/releases no longer working.

Answer (score 6):

I finally found where the gEdit plugins are stored. Try putting the two files to whatever plugin here: `/usr/lib/gedit/plugins`.

Answer (score 2):

I have a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the folder with the plugins is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/`

Copying inside it the `*.plugin` and `*.py` files made the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

For Auto install, try the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gedit-bc-dev-plugins/releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
sudo apt-get install gedit-projects-plugin
```

Answer (score 1):

For easy installation of additional 3rd party plugins there is a plugin installer plugin

```
https://github.com/lwindolf/gedit-plugininstaller
```

which might simplify discovering and installing plugins.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gedit-plugin-text-size
```