# gedit-r-plugin not showing up in plugin list in gedit

Tags: 11.10, gedit, r

I installed the gedit-r-plugin through synaptic and in the past it has worked great.  I can't seem to even get the plugin to show up in the Preferences -> Plugins list after updating to 11.10.  I'm guessing this is because of the switch to gtk3 but I'm at a loss for what to do.  What can I do to resolve this and get the ability to work with R nicely through gedit again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct - the move to GTK3 has broken this plugin.

Fortunately - this has been resolved in the very latest code available in [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rgedit/files/).

If you want to compile this code, you will need to manually install the plugin as per the Linked Question below.

Unless this plugin gets a SRU - dont expect it to land in the Oneiric repo's.  Probably will though for Precise.

Until then - you could always try downloading the [GTK3 deb](http://packages.debian.org/sid/all/gedit-r-plugin/download) file from the Debian Sid Repo's

**to install**

First install from synaptic the gedit-r-plugin available in synaptic.  This will ensure all dependent packages are also installed.

Then download the Debian Sid .deb (link above)

Install with the syntax:

```
sudo dpkg -i [filename.deb]
```

After installation - you should see it appear in the preferences - plugins screen:

[image]

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I install a plugin for gEdit v3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61785/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-for-gedit-v3/61786#61786)

Comment: Looks to provide a really good answer.  Thank you!  As soon as I can try it out and make sure it works I'll accept it.

Comment: The Debian Sid .deb didn't work for me.  It added the right menus and but none of them produced any of the desired results.  When I have some more time I'll try the other method.

Comment: I finally got it working.  Downloading the source and installing it manually worked.  If anybody else tries this note that you have to install it into ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/ and if you try to install to /usr/lib/gedit/plugins/ it will yell at you.