# Finding the gedit plugin folder

Tags: gedit, plugins

I am a bit confused as to where I should put externally downloaded plugins. I have tried putting them in:

1. `/usr/share/gedit/plugins`
2. `~/. Local/gedit/plugins`
3. `~/. Gnome2/gedit/plugins`
4. `/usr/lib/gedit/plugins`

The way I have checked whether the plugins show up or not is going to Edit -> Preferences -> Plugins and looking for the ones I have downloaded (clickconfig, gedit-developer-plugins-...). Since I do not see any new plugins appearing, I have to assume that I am doing something wrong.

None of these have worked. I am a bit tired of polluting my system. It's probably my own fault as it's written somewhere I have not thought to look. Please let me know how to add external plugins to Gedit properly. I am running Ubuntu 11.10. My Gedit version is 3.2.3

---

EDIT:

I am still not able to solve this problem. I have tried the following folder now as well, and it hasn't worked:

`~/. Config/gedit/plugins`

EDIT 2:

I am trying to install the plugins in "gedit-developer-plugins" as well as the "clickconfig" plugin.

Comment: You should add the plugins you want to install in your post.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/61785/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-for-gedit-v3/61786#61786

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, I'll answer the question about the specific plugins. [gedit-developer-plugins [image: Install gedit-developer-plugins]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gedit-developer-plugins) is available in the official Ubuntu archive, and I'd suggest installing it from there. `clickconfig`, on the other hand, unfortunately does not seem to have been ported to to Gedit 3 and is not compatible.

More generally, for Gedit 3 (which is in Ubuntu 11.10 and above) local plugins should be installed to `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins` The `.plugin` file must be in that exact directory, sub-directories are not scanned. For instance, here's the file layout of mine:

```
$ tree ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
/home/andrew/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
├── markdown-preview
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   └── locale
│       └── fr
│           └── LC_MESSAGES
│               └── markdown-preview.mo
├── markdown-preview.plugin
├── reSt-preview
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.pyc
└── reSt-preview.plugin
```

Comment: Do you know whether it still works with Ubuntu 14.04/Gedit 3.10.4? Because for me, your solution doesn't work. Interestingly, the folder ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/ didn't even exist, although Gedit has some plugins activated. Did they change something?

Answer (score 2):

From the official docs on the [gedit website](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-plugins-install.html.en), the folder is: `/home/username/.local/share/gedit/plugins`. If this folder does not exist, you will have to create it

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I had to create the folders as per the hierarchy mentioned and copy my plugin's `.plugin` & `.py` files into that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
~/.config/gedit/plugins
```

Worked for me in 11.10.

Im now using

```
~/.local/share/gedit/plugins
```

in 12.04. Don't ask me why..

Comment: Sorry, this did not work for me.

Comment: Some plugins are not compatible with gedit3. If it doesnt mention gedit3 on the web page or README, it's probably not.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I looked for everywhere then I found it in

```
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit
```

I didn't expect it there too. Do look there.