# Where does gedit store it's plugin configuration and preferences?

Tags: gedit

I have gedit-plugins installed for gedit on my previously broken system. On the new system, I want to restore gedit from my backed up home directory.

I will like to know! Where does gedit store it's configurations including plugins list, preferences etc.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: We have a search feature on this site ;) http://askubuntu.com/questions/146999/finding-the-gedit-plugin-folder

Answer (score 1):

From my backup, I found the file I need at [backup-tape]/.config/gedit/saved-session.xml, then I re-installed the gedit-plugins package and enabled "Session saver" plugin.