# Where do I find the local and the gedit plugins folders in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, directory, gedit, plugins

I know this will be likely marked as a duplicate. But none of the answers in [Finding the gedit plugin folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146999/finding-the-gedit-plugin-folder) can solve my problem.
It seems that I don't have a gedit plugins folder. Is there any easy way to find it?
I tried up with all possible paths but it seems that there is no such a folder.

What is also strange is that I don't have a local folder. Does the local folder have another name in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: The local folder is still `~/.local` in Ubuntu 14.04. And if `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins` does not exist, you can/should create it. (`~/.local/share` should exist already, though.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gedit plugins that are installed by your package manager will go in:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/
```

or

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/
```

or

```
/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/
```

Your "local" plugins, those that you installed from source are usually found in:

```
~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Sylvian answer above,

**Gedit 3 plugins that are installed by my package manager were in:**

```
/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/
```

My "local" plugins, those that you installed from source were found in:

```
~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/
```

Comment: You can suggest an edit to that post: http://askubuntu.com/posts/538123/edit