# Install Regex plugin for Gedit

Tags: gedit, plugins, regex

I am using `Ubuntu 12.04`.I want to install `Regex Search and Replace plugin for Gedit`.So can some one please tell me where can I `get it and install it`.Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Download [Regular Expression Plugin  for Gedit 3](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=regex_replace-gedit3.tar.gz). Extract the tar package , then copy it to Gedit plugins directory from the Extracted folder.

For a particular user , do

```
 cd ~/Downloads
 wget 'https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=regex_replace-gedit3.tar.gz' -o regex_replace-gedit3.tar.gz
 tar xf regex_replace-gedit3.tar.gz
 mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins 
 mv ~/Downloads/regex_replace ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins
```

And for the all the users in system

```
sudo cp -r ~/Downloads/regex_replace /usr/lib/gedit/plugins/
```

After copying the plugin you can enable it in Gedit 3 under Edit > Preferences, clicking on Plugins tab and checking the box for **Regex Search and Replace**.

Another alternate is also available as [Advanced Find / Replace](http://code.google.com/p/advanced-find/)

P.S. : Thanks [mac9416](https://askubuntu.com/users/130/mac9416) for suggesting the individual User part.

Comment: Someone posted very thorough instructions for install Gedit 3 plugins: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61785/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-for-gedit-v3

It might be easier to use the user's plugin directory.

`mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins`
`cp /home/user/Downloads/regex_replace ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins`

Comment: Thanks , you are really free to edit it for making it to include better content from next time :)

Comment: Thanks @tijybba..it worked for me but I got an error when trying to copy.The error was `cp: omitting directory `regex_replace'`.
Finally I had to use `sudo cp -r`.That worked perfectly for me.Can you tell me what is the shortcut key to the regex search when using gedit?

Comment: Since Gedit 3 comes with a inbuilt `Replace` option at `Ctrl+H` , there is no shortcut specified , but you can access it under **`Search`** menu bar as `Regular Expression` , i know it is inconvenient w/o shortcut . I will post the Shortcut if i find out :)

Comment: Everything is OK except the link [Regular Expression Plugin for Gedit 3](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=regex_replace-gedit3.tar.gz). I downloaded [this](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Plugins?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=regex_replace-gedit3.tar.gz)

Comment: Seems to be no longer working in Ubuntu 13.10, Gedit 3.8.3.

Answer (score 1):

The best plugin I have found is `Advanced find / replace plugin for gedit` that you can find in http://code.google.com/p/advanced-find/.

About how to install, you can follow the instructions in its wiki page http://code.google.com/p/advanced-find/wiki/Installation.

Basically what you must do is:

1. Download the correct version for your gedit from http://code.google.com/p/advanced-find/downloads/list.
2. Decompress it.
3. Run install.sh (without sudo).
4. Go to preferences / plug-in and activate it.

It have many many features like search in opened files or bookmark a search.

[image: Screen capture of Advanced Find/Replace dialog opened]

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this because all the links to the other one seem dead. Edit: Which this one will be too soon unless they move from Google Code.

Comment: @powerbuoy Yes, but in this case, we will have the clone on my own account in github https://github.com/PhoneixS/advanced-find

Answer (score 0):

At least for Ubuntu 14.04, there is a regex plugin available from the `gedit-developers-plugins` package. If this package doesn't work for you, as it didn't work for me, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/361879/228958) is the solution.