# Wildcards in gedit

Tags: gedit

Is there a way to use wildcards in gedit's search and replace function? I really don't want to have to install anything or try or have to figure out how to use a 3rd party plugin—I installed the advanced find and replace plugin, yet there is absolutely zero information on how to use the thing.

Comment: what plugin it is ?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/173785/install-regex-plugin-for-gedit. As for how to use it, there are two fields, search and replace and standard regex applies.

Answer (score 3):

Taking your question literally, there is a ridiculous/extreme way to enable wildcards without installing any additional plugins.

1. First, go to **edit/preferences/plugins** and **enable the python
   console**. This plugin should be installed by default.
2. Hit ctrl-f9 to open the bottom panel and expose the console
3. Paste the following code into the console and hit enter:

   ```
   #function to replace stuff
   import re
   def replace(re1,re2):
       doc = window.get_active_document()
       start, end = doc.get_bounds()
       txt = start.get_slice(end)      
       newtxt = re.sub(re1,re2,txt)    
       doc.set_text(newtxt)
   ```
4. For demo purposes, paste the above code into your gedit document
5. Now, from the console, you can use regular expressions with wildcards like so: `replace(r'function.*',r'new comment')`

Pretty fun, right? :)