# Gedit plugins not working after upgrading from version 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, python, gedit

Some Gedit plugins (for example codecomment) are not working after upgrading from version 12.04 to 14.04. When I go in Preferences->Plugins and check the box of one of those plugins, I get a message on the terminal :

```
(gedit:15457): libpeas-WARNING **: Could not find loader 'python3' for plugin 'codecomment'
```

I already tried to edit the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/codecomment.plugin` to change `Loader=python3` to `Loader=python` as suggested in other posts, but it doesn't fix the problem, I get the message

```
libpeas-WARNING **: Could not find loader 'python' for plugin 'codecomment'
```

I have python3 correctly installed. Does anyone know how to fix this, seems to be around for quite long time.

Update: the problem does not appear when I start gedit from the Applications menu, but only when I start gedit from a terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/61785/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-for-gedit-v3

Comment: look & see if there is a /usr/lib/gedit/plugins folder. The location changed from 12.04 to 14.04, maybe it was left behind & interfering somehow . Also try in a guest session to see if gedit performs as expected there.

Comment: Indeed there is no /usr/lib/gedit/plugins folder. My plugins are still located in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins. Also, in a guest session gedit works well. What do you suggest to do?

Comment: I also tried to uninstall Gedit and the plugins, and re-install. Still missing the folder  /usr/lib/gedit/ and the plugins not working

Comment: You don't want /usr/lib/gedit.  Seeing that a guest session works then you have some local config or setting that is borking this up for you. That's one of the downsides to  upgrading over such a large timeframe, things change. I'd look in home folder/.gconf, see if anything to do with gedit is in there. If so remove. Also maybe see what's in ~/.config/gedit/, there should be nothing to do with plugins in there. (in 14.04 gedit saves those settings in gsettings(dconf. Worst case you could just reset dconf to new install defaults & reset your preferences (will extend to other app's settings

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem: in the file .bash_rc I had the LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to some Matlab libraries. Commenting this line solve the problem (not sure why though).